# Changing div styles at scroll position without JQuery

Tags: javascript, css

I am relatively new to web design and am not yet ready to dive into JQuery but I am beginning to use Javascript as needed. I am unable to figure out how to change the background color of a div menubar at a certain scroll position.

CSS

```
.mainMenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Javascript

```
var scrollHeight = window.pageYOffset;

if (scrollHeight >= 100) {
    document.getElementById("mainMenu").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

From what I can tell as a noob, the if statement only runs on load and the var scrollHeight isn't updating as the user scrolls. I appreciate any help making this work! I will get around to learning JQuery but I would like to understand the language better before dabbling in libraries.

Comment: Before you become a great coder, you must become a great searcher. Haha. Seriously though, this topic is covered all over the internet. Search along the lines of "javascript detect scrolling position"

Comment: The internet is full of resources discussing scroll position. But I was confused by the various methods to iterate the scroll function, as it seems there are multiple options and I couldn't seem to make any work. It seems like 90% or more of these resources also utilize JQuery so I plan to learn it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right – you need to setup something that continues to check the scroll position and update accordingly:

```
function checkPosition() {

  // Continue calling this function:
  requestAnimationFrame(checkPosition);

  // Check your position here

}
// Initial Call:
checkPosition();
```

Better yet, read up on [Scroll Events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp).

Edit:

Also, instead of manipulating styles directly, I'd recommend adding or removing classes:

```
element.classList.add("newClass");
```

(By the way, jQuery is actually easier than 'regular' javascript.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I read up on the requestAnimationFrame() function - pretty nifty. What is the benefit to adding classes rather than manipulating styles in Javascript?

Comment: Lots of benefits, actually. For one – separation of concerns: you can keep all your style information in your css, and your javascript can focus just on function. 

But beyond that, it's easier to keep track of things. Instead of adding a color of #F00, and then trying to undo that change, you could just toggle a class of "alert" on and off again.

Comment: @PhilipJarrett Modularity, flexibility, and ease of management. The pros far outweigh any cons. Put styles in a stylesheet and you'll be happy you did.